# HTML image file input only allows user to choose from the gallery

Tags: html, input, file-upload

When press the input on mobile devices, it shows two options: one is camera and one is gallery. But I only want to choose from the gallery. How can I disable camera option ?

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly this cannot be done correctly, despite the fact that much of the Web is mobile first.

However, a dirty trick is to do the following:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/octet-stream" />
```

It's not an elegant solution, but it's a workaround that works.

**Important:** I have tried it on Firefox/Android, I don't know if it works the same on IOS or in another browsers.

*Check the Fiddle:* [Input File Examples](https://jsfiddle.net/tyj9qz81/7/)

Comment: Still show 2 options (camera and gallery).I tested on my android mobile phone using gg chrome

Comment: You're right, I tried it in chrome and it doesn't behave like it does in Firefox (my fault).

If you absolutely need to block the behavior, you would have to limit the user to using Firefox for this functionality (although this is not a good practice).

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.